# Save datepicker to userdefaults and set value on load

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, uidatepicker

Trying to save datePicker date when changed as UserDefaults and set the datePicker date if this UserDefaults exists.

I have done research but everything I have found seems old and isn't working.

I seem to be having an issue setting the date from the saved UserDefaults. Pretty sure I'm doing this wrong. I'm just learning Xcode/Swift so I apologize if this should be obvious.

Saving date:

```
@IBOutlet weak var NotificationTime: UIDatePicker!
let notificationTimeKey = "notificationTime"

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Not sure how to set the date
    if let dateValue = defaults.value(forKey: notificationTimeKey){
        NotificationTime.date = dateValue as! NSDate <--- Cannot assign value of type 'NSDate?' to type 'Date'
    }
}  

@IBAction func updateNotificationTime(_ sender: Any){
    let selectedDate = NotificationTime.date
    UserDefaults().set(selectedDate, forKey: notificationTimeKey)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for reading the date from UserDefaults and setting the date picker's `date` should be:

```
if let dateValue = defaults.object(forKey: notificationTimeKey) as? Date {
    NotificationTime.date = dateValue
}
```

Never use `value(forKey:)` unless you have a clear and understood reason to use key-value coding.

And don't use `NSDate` in Swift.

Also, variable and method names should start with lowercase letters. You should name your outlet `notificationTime`. Class and struct names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Excellent thanks for the quick response that worked. Thanks for the suggestions, I was going to do that for notificationTime, believe that was the first one I added.

Answer (score 0):

I found another answer similar to the above code from Redit by 'chriswaco' https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcode/comments/faxfa8/how_do_you_save_a_date_form_a_date_picker/

Works in iOS 14 and Xcode 12.

SAVE: (put this within the DatePicker action func)

```
 let theDate = datePicker.date
 UserDefaults.standard.set( theDate, forKey:"myDateKey")
```

READBACK, i.e. (ViewDidLoad)

```
 if let savedDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"myDateKey") as? Date{
    // do something with savedDate here
 }
```

Credit to chriswaco in Redit.